# Doctrine and PostgreSQL array of a custom type

Tags: arrays, doctrine, postgresql-9.2

I would need to handle an array of a custom type of PostgreSQL in Doctrine.

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE name_surname AS( 
    name varchar, 
    surname varchar);

CREATE TABLE test(
    id serial,
    data name_surname[]);
```

I have seen some (pretty old) posts about managing arrays of a predefined type, but nothing about arrays of a custom type. Is it natively possible in current versions of Doctrine?
If not, would this be solvable by adding custom types in Doctrine?

Thanks.